# Google spreadsheet, search for a value and pull data from columns next to it

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm looking for a formula that searches an entire sheet for the same value ("Boland1" is the value in my picture example), and pulls data from the right of it. Is this possible with any formula? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Use `query()` with an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276), like this:

`=query( { A3:B, H3:I }, "where Col1 = 'Boland1' ", 0 )`

Comment: Thank you, but I forgot to mention that there will other names between the second "boland1" and the third "Boland1", how do I approach that?

Comment: Edited the answer. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: Thank you. One last question before i give u the solve mark. Is there any formula you know that performs like you showed me but Instead of searching for specific columns, it just searches the entire sheet for the word "Boland1" and returns the first value to the right of it?

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).

Comment: This was my original question, your answer can be used but it didn't "answer" my original question. I asked to search through the entire sheet, you gave me an answer that searches specific columns.

Comment: I would recommend that you post a new question and clearly specify your exact requirements. Also show _realistic-looking_ sample data and your _manually entered_ desired results. Optimally, share a [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Comment: @Axxi, Since your question is "anywhere on the sheet", your search criteria will need to be moved to a different sheet, otherwise it will be picked up as a result because it is currently somewhere (part of your "anywhere") on the sheet.